# Повесить картинку на кнопку

Tags: javascript, html, jquery

Как можно повесить картинку на кнопку?

```js
function make_pay() {
  if (($('#price').val() == '') || (!/^-?(?:\d+|\d{1,3}(?:,\d{3})+)(?:\.\d+)?$/.test($('#price').val()))) {
    $('#price').css('border-color', 'red');
  } else
    $.get("/payment/makeform.php", {
        price: $('#price').val(),
        desc: $('#desc').val(),
      },
      onAjaxSuccess
    );

  function onAjaxSuccess(data) {
    $('#form_responce').html(data);
    $('#form_responce form').submit()
  }
}
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.4/jquery.min.js"></script>
<form>
  <input id="price" name="price" type="hidden" value="1000">
  <button type="button" onclick="make_pay();" class="btn btn_green">Оплатить</button>
  <span id='form_responce' style='display:none;'></span>
</form>
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Так?

```js
function make_pay() {
  alert("Hello");
}
```

```css
img {
  width: 40px;
  vertical-align: middle;
}
```

```html
<img src="https://cdn.sstatic.net/Sites/stackoverflow/img/apple-touch-icon@2.png?v=73d79a89bded" onclick="make_pay();">
```

Comment: Нет так не работает <button type="button" onclick="make_pay();" class="btn btn_green">Оплатить</button>

Comment: Так вопрос же в том, чтобы повесить картинку на кнопку. Или я что-то не понимаю в вопросе? Работа кнопки уже другое.

Comment: Получается нужно на кнопку повесить картинку, точнее картинка стала кнопкой, я испробовал всё что мог не у  меня не получилось , то картинка сверху кнопки то картинка внутри кнопки именно всё в этой строке кода где есть событие <button type="button" onclick="make_pay();" class="btn btn_green">Оплатить</button>

Comment: Обновил код, теперь картинка это кнопка. Она реагирует на нажатие на картинку.

Comment: Огромное Вам спасибо, это просто супер , всё работает как надо . С уважением к вам .

Comment: Если ответ решил вашу проблему, вы можете его принять.