# Нужна помощь, нужно на кнопку повесить картинку

Tags: html

```html
<head>

    <title></title>

</head>

<body>

    <form action="https://api.privatbank.ua/p24api/ishop" method="post">

      <input name="amt" type="hidden" value="[UESCAPE_PRICE, 1, ###.@@]">
        
      <input name="ccy" type="hidden"value="UAH">
      
      <input name="merchant" type="hidden" value="76282">

      <input name="order" type="hidden" value="[UESCAPE_ORDER_NO]">

      <input name="details" type="hidden" value="Оплата услуг [UESCAPE_ORDER_NO]">

      <input name="ext_details" type="hidden" value="Номер заказа  [UESCAPE_ORDER_NO]">
      
      <input name="pay_way" type="hidden" value="privat24"> <input name="return_url" type="hidden" value="/good-payment.html">
      
      <input name="server_url"type="hidden" value="/good-payment.html">
      
      <input name="amt"type="submit" value="оплатить">

    </form>

</body>
```

Comment: `<button><img src="myimg.jpg"></button>`

Comment: Здравствуйте, так в вашем примере получается картинка поверх кнопки, а нужно чтобы каринка стала кнопкой

Comment: Дубликат(ваш же): [ссылка](https://ru.stackoverflow.com/questions/846179/Повесить-картинку-на-кнопку/846182#846182)

Comment: так не выходит как в том примере,что был ранее

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Можно самому `input` задать тип - изображение и повесить на него `submit`.

```html
<form onsubmit="alert('Hello')">
  <input type="image" name="submit" src="https://cdn.sstatic.net/Sites/stackoverflow/img/apple-touch-icon@2.png?v=73d79a89bded" alt="Submit" style="width:40px;"/>
</form>
```

Comment: ОГРОМНОЕ СПАСИБО ВАМ ! Вы меня опять выручили, с уважением к вам!